# relational algebra to SQL converter or vice versa

Tags: sql, converters, relational, relational-algebra

i would like to check if my relational algebra statements are correct, so is there a program out there that outputs relational algebra equivalent of an SQL query?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of one. There isn't a relational algebra equivalent of every SQL query and not every RA expression has an equivalent in SQL.

You might want to check out [Rel](http://dbappbuilder.sourceforge.net/Rel.php) which is based on Tutoral D - a truly relational language much more like the RA.